# SharePoint 2013 Meeting/Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to develop the SharePoint 2013 Meeting Calendar with the below functionality using OOTB :-

1. SharePoint trigger email which tell about all the meeting in a day. Example 24 or 48 hour a email shoots to the recipient list about all the meetings in a day in one email, using SharePoint 2013 designer Workflow
2. The User will manually enter the number of hours in all the meetings. So it should show in calendar view the total hours spent in all meetings on a particular day. Example on 20th November: 7 hours(includes multiple meeting- number shows the sum of all the meeting hours)

I have tried a lot but not able to succeed and i really need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Kishan

Comment: For the second requirement is it per user basis or it should calculate total meeting hours for a day in that calendar?

Answer (score 0):

First of all triggering email on a daily basis is not fall into the workflow category. Workflows are there to automate business processes.

For this type of requirement you should develop a SharePoint timer job. And schedule it to run every night. The job should pick up the events for next day and sent it to respective persons. This approach has following advantages

1. Easily to develop using Visual Studio
2. You can easily query the next day events using CAML queries which are efficient. You can use CAML Query Builder for real time testing.